# How to send sms messages with django and AWS SNS with phone numbers stored in a database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, amazon-sns

I am making an application with django that does the following, when a user presses a physical button , the button sends a POST request to django-rest which then creates a ticket , at the same time it creates the ticket it sends a sms notification to a phone stored in an SQL database . The phone number corresponds to someone who can help with the problem the user that pressed the button is having.

I have tried to think how while handling the POST request in the server I can query the table that has the phone numbers and then with the phone number send the sms but I cant think of a way.

I expect that when the user presses the physical button a support ticket is created and the person responsible for helping with the ticket recieves a sms notification on the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you managed to solve this but for anyone still looking for an answer using AWS SNS is pretty simple.

Create a user with the below permission or if you prefer you can attach it to an existing user/role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "sns:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sns:Publish"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Install [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html) so that you can interact with AWS.

In order to send an SMS, create a client for the "sns" resource and call publish on it.

```
import boto3

# Create an SNS client
client = boto3.client(
    "sns",
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
)

# Send your sms message.
client.publish(
    PhoneNumber="YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER_IN_E.164_FORMAT",
    Message="This is Amazon SNS service talking!"
)
```

Make sure you're not spamming people. You might have to request AWS to [increase your SMS sending limits](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sns-text-messaging) as it defaults to 1 USD.

Comment: hello resley, i am trying with aws sns in django. but i dont understand these 
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Deny",?? what are these? where to put them in the code?

Comment: Those are permissions to be attached to a user or role.